# Unable to create table in Qubole similar to mysql

Tags: mysql, hive, qubole

I want to create a external table in Qubole similar to a table created in Mysql. Query for create table in mysql is:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
 `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `v_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `l_visited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `f_visited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

can anyone help me to write similar query in hive.

Comment: Hey, rather than directly asking for solution, can you please start with some simple query and then ask for help when you are struck?

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
CREATE TABLE page_view(viewTime INT, userid BIGINT,
                page_url STRING, referrer_url STRING,
                ip STRING COMMENT 'IP Address of the User')
COMMENT 'This is the page view table'
PARTITIONED BY(dt STRING, country STRING)
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE;
```

Follow this links:
[link1](http://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/faqs/hive/can-create-table-hdfs.html)

[link2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-Creating,Showing,Altering,andDroppingTables)

Comment: how to use "not null" and "default null" in hive